# how to initialize List in java of an abstract type so I can add sub types to the list later

Tags: java, list, collections, abstract-class

tldr: how to create List of abstract type BankAccount and add concrete sub types to the list

In java I have a class called BankAccount.  Its an abstract class because I don't want anyone to use a regular BankAccount ever, they should be using the sub types SavingsAccount, CheckingAccount, VacationAccount.

I want to have a property in a customer class that is List called accounts.  In the class definition i added a property just like that and didnt initialize it to anything. In the constructor I want to add an account based on what the user specified in the constructor, however when i do this i get an error on the call to add().

It looks something like this

```
List<BankAccount> accounts;

accounts.add(new CheckingAccount() );
```

Should this work?  What am I doing wrong. I tried doing

```
List<BankAccount> accounts = new List<BankAccount>();
```

but that doesnt work.

Comment: You can't instantiate a list, you need to pick an implementation.

Comment: I had no idea! lol.  I'm coming from .NET where a List is a List, an ArrayList is an ArrayList etc

Comment: actually, that makes a lot of sense.  I can do the same in .NET, but its more recognizable to me because interfaces start with 'I'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you meant:

```
List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
```

[List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is just an interface, you should use a concrete implementation when creating an instance, such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for example.

Comment: You might want to give the variable a name as well.